# Running Ubuntu on an HP t5710

Tags: software-installation

I acquired several t5710 thin clients a while back, which all run on XPe. I would like to replace the OS with one that is still supported, and a net search for a version of Ubuntu came up empty.

Is there a version of Ubuntu that I can boot onto these machines? I want to use them to access a server as an admin terminal, one server running Ubuntu (not set up yet) and one a legacy Magnia SG20.

Comment: you can always use ubuntu live cd to check which version is supported buy your HP laptop. 15.10 is latest.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net).  Lubuntu runs with lower hardware requirements, and therefore it will run faster on an older machine.

Just make an install CD/DVD/USB of it and install it.